# Why no note sound when clicking button on iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioengine

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {


    @IBAction func SoundPlay(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let engine = AVAudioEngine()
        let sampler=AVAudioUnitSampler()
        engine.attach(sampler)
        engine.connect(sampler, to:engine.mainMixerNode,format: nil)
        do{
            try engine.start()
            if let url=Bundle.main.url (forResource:"healin01",withExtension:"wav")
            {
                try sampler.loadAudioFiles(at:[url])
            }
        }
        catch
        {print("Couldnt")}

        sampler.startNote(36, withVelocity: 90, onChannel: 0)
```

No error message
File sound in root folder and second copy in subfolder of project
Im trying to play a note clicking on button

Comment: Check if `healin01` is added to target or not

Comment: Thanks but doesn't help

Comment: do i need func viewDidLoad? Cause i can't add it

Comment: `Bundle.main.url (forResource:"healin01",withExtension:"wav")` returns a url?

Comment: I don't know. How to check it?